# How to get browser information in JSP?

Tags: jsp

How do you get Client IP and Browser information using JSP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the browser part you need to parse the reqeust's User-Agent section.

```
String browserType = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

There you'll find the relevant information...

Answer (score 12):

The following jsp will output your ip address and user-agent:

```
Your user-agent is: <%=request.getHeader("user-agent")%><br/>
Your IP address is: <%=request.getRemoteAddr()%><br/>
```

To find out what browser and/or OS the user is using, parse the user-agent header.

For example:

```
<%
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
if (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
  out.println("Your browser is Microsoft Internet Explorer<br/>");
}
%>
```

For a list of user agents, look [here](http://www.user-agents.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) or the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header, if you think you can trust it.

What sort of browser information? The request headers will have the User-Agent.

Answer (score 1):

```
String browser=request.getHeader("user-agent");
String browsername = "";
String browserversion = "";
String[] otherBrowsers={"Firefox","Chrome","Chrome","Safari"};
    if(browser != null ){
        if((browser.indexOf("MSIE") == -1) && (browser.indexOf("msie") == -1)){
            for(int i=0; i< otherBrowsers.length;  i++){
                System.out.println(browser.indexOf(otherBrowsers[i]));
                browsername=otherBrowsers[i];
                break;
            }
            String subsString = browser.substring( browser.indexOf(browsername));
            String Info[] = (subsString.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
            browsername = Info[0];
            browserversion = Info[1];
    }
    else{
        String tempStr = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("MSIE"),browser.length());
            browsername    = "IE"
        browserversion = tempStr.substring(4,tempStr.indexOf(";"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) you can find getRemoteAddr(), which

> Returns the fully qualified name of the client or the last proxy that sent the request

...and with this you (maybe) retrieve the browser

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information the client is willing to give you through HTTP headers. [Here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)'s a complete list of them.

To access the header in a servlet or JSP, use:

request.getHeader("name-of-the-header-you-want");